# JBoss Tools - Disabling Visual Editor

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I just added JBoss tools and I like a lot of what I get from it. However, I noticed that my .xhtml files are loading a /lot/ slower (on the order of several seconds) than before I installed JBoss tools. I'm willing to accept some slowdown (there's always overhead from using tooling sitting ontop of Eclipse) but this is a pretty long wait. I suspect it has to do with the visual editor that JBoss has added for .xhtml. I am using windows 64 bit and I can't use this editor. I've also tried  following the advice at this link

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/vpe/vpe-news-3.3.0.M2.html

and adding -Dorg.jboss.tools.vpe.loadxulrunner=false to the eclipse.ini but I didn't notice any speedups. I also uninstalled the plugin for the JBoss visual editor and didn't see any results. After uninstalling the plugin the visual/source, source, and preview tabs are still at the bottom of the .xhtml editor, so maybe I uninstalled the wrong one?

I'm using Eclipse for Java EE Juno service release 1 Build id: 20120920-0800. I have the CDI, dynamic web module, Java, javascript, JSF 2.1, JAX-RS 1.1 JBoss Maven Integration 1.0 and JPA 2.0 facets installed on this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to say what you just uninstalled.

If you want just uninstall visual editor you can do such thing:

- Just install onece again Eclipse and when you install JBoss Tools just doesn't select visual editor
- Try to unistall visual editor. I think (but *I never tested it*) you should remove from *plugins* and *features* directoris wich starts from **org.jboss.tools.vpe**

I don't know if there can be some problems with dependencies and so on - you should make backup of Eclipse directory before making any changes.

Maybe it will be sufficient just open the files with other editor:

- You can just open single file using other editor, just click in *Package explorer* view on the file with right click and choose *Open with...* menu - then you can open the file with for example HTML editor:
  [image]
- You can change the default editor for all files by open *Window->Preferences* menu and find *Find associations* position. There should be ***.xhtml** extensions - choose it and change the default editor.
  [image]

Comment: Perfect, opening it in the html editor allowed me to keep the JBoss autocompletion without dealing with the cruft of the visual editor.